# Flutter sign in with facebook

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api, flutter

I'm trying to sign my users in with facebook.
Therefor, I use this code:

```
 FacebookLoginResult facebookLoginResult = await _handleFBSignIn();
        final accessToken = facebookLoginResult.accessToken.token;
        if (facebookLoginResult.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
          setState(() {
            isSaving = true;
          });

          final facebookAuthCred =
              FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: accessToken);
          final user =
              await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCred);

          final graphResponse = await http.get(
              'https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,friends,email&access_token=$accessToken');
          final profile = jsonDecode(graphResponse.body);

          if (profile['id'] != null) {
            setState(() {
              facebookID = profile['id'];
            });
          }

  Future<FacebookLoginResult> _handleFBSignIn() async {
    FacebookLogin facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    FacebookLoginResult facebookLoginResult =
        await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 'user_friends']);
    switch (facebookLoginResult.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        print("Cancelled");
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
        print("error");
        break;
      case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        print("Logged In");
        break;
    }
    return facebookLoginResult;
  }
```

This works perfectly on android, but on ios I get an error.

```
flutter: Cancelled
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'token' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

So I'm assuming it has something to do with my info.plist because android doesn't have the problem. I looked in my info.plist but can't find anything...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>drinkm8</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Hiermee kunt u een verhaal maken</string>
    <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Your prompt</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Always/When in use description</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Can I haz location always?</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Hiermee kunt u een verhaal maken</string>
    <key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Motion Usage Description</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Hiermee kunt u een foto selecteren</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Hiermee kunt u een foto opslaan</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <string>NO</string>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <!-- TODO Replace this value: -->
                <!-- Copied from GoogleService-Info.plist key REVERSED_CLIENT_ID -->
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.myappid</string>
                <string>fb4856myappid</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>4856myappid</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>DRINKM8</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
    <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <string>YES</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Is there a step I missed to install FB for ios (I only edited my info.plist and added fb sign in to the pubspec yaml)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned from github it's an error in the package or sdk or ....

But for IOS, it works if you use this:

```
final fbLogin =FacebookLogin();
fbLogin.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webViewOnly;
```